# php sqlite driver missing?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, driver

I am trying to connect to an existing database I created via DB browser for SQLite. It is saved as a file on my computer.
When using getAvailableDrivers, I am getting both MySQL and SQLite.
In phpinfo() I have the following entries:
PDO
PDO drivers -> MySQL, SQLite
pdo_sqlite
SQLite library -> 3.8.10.2
SQLite3
SQLite3 module version -> 0.7-dev
SQLite Library 3.9.10.2
SQLite3 extension dir -> c:\xampp\SQLite

I have written the following code to just establish connection:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
$handler = new PDO('SQLite3:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', '', '');
?>
```

But when I try it I get the following error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ebsco\Users.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ebsco\Users.php(4): PDO->__construct('SQLite3:host=12...', '', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ebsco\Users.php on line 4

I have searched several places online and several answers on Stack Overflow, but they did not help with a solution.

Any idea what could be causing this?
I noticed that the dir in the error message is not the same directory which I specified in the php.ini (which is also returned by phpinfo();), but I'm not sure if that is the cause, and if so what is causing it to search for the driver in that location.

Comment: it is `sqlite`, not `SQLite3`, and you don't need `host` part. It works with local files. Pease read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php

Comment: So I just write 'SQLite; database path'?

Comment: Have you read the docs? It has handful of examples.

Comment: I did, though it took me a while to understand exactly what they meant (the sources I've read before were for MySql so I had to change a few things).

I ended up with the following:
{$handler = new PDO('sqlite:Ebsco.db');

And at least for now I'm not showing any errors when running my php. But how do I know if I'm actually connected to the database?

Comment: How do you know it with mysql?

Comment: Because the video was called something with MySql and the guy was talking about MySql :D

Comment: I meant how do you know you are actually connected to the database when you are using mysql

Comment: I'm not using MySql, I'm using SQLite, hence the question to begin with, since I only found MySql instructions and the documentation for PHP SQLite is far from clear, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, I see. Somehow I've got an impression you know how to work with mysql. Okay then, you need to invest some time in education and read the docs or some tutorials to get basic concepts of how PDO works in general.